# Win-Server 2019 login screen blank on rdp

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, login-screen, windows-server-2019, remote-login

Every now and then we have 1-2 servers at a time that don't allow remote logins.

After connecting to the system via RDP (already providing login info) the login screen stays blank and doesn't log in the user:

[Picture of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX0S1.jpg)

I can't figure out what that issue is about. Most times only a/several restarts over Vmware is helping.

Comment: Got something similar on my side. Have you tried pressing the Esc-key or Windows Key? Have you tried to drag the screen up as if it unlocked that way?

Comment: @VarmintLP, yea we tried the usual keyboard shortcuts and things to try to unlock. Nothing changes anything on the system appearance.

Comment: From what OS are you connecting to the Win-Server 2019 via RDP? Windows, MacOS or Linux?

Comment: @VarmintLP, we are all connecting from Windows 10 20H2